# Disable Google account additional security

Tags: google-account, google-workspace-for-business, g-suite-administrator, multi-factor-auth

Google forces me to verify my account on second device when is identified attempt to login from new location with message below

> This device isn't recognized. For your security, Google wants to make sure it's really you.

I have found in console possibility to temporarily disable this feature for 10 minutes in `Google Apps admin console > user > Security check during login > suspend for 10 minutes`

Where can I disable this feature for eternity? All other 2FA features are disabled and Google still forces me this feature

Answer (score 0):

Disabling "Verify it's you" dialog consists of several steps

1. Remove your Google account from your Android Device (Simply stop using Mail application and use Outlook for instance)
2. Wait for a week until Google realizes you are not using this device anymore
3. Remove secondary email and telephone number

Now you won't be bothered by Google's "verify it's you" dialog